# Is this considered insertion sort ? it's working for me but the solution is different from the regular algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, insertion-sort

Here I am assigning the a[j] inside the loop.

Regular algorithms do that after the loop is finished, so is this considered like the regular insertion sort ?

```
int l=a.length;
        for(int i=1;i<=l-1;i++) {
            int value=a[i];
            int j;
            for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--) {
                if(value<a[j]) {
                a[j+1]=a[j];
                a[j]=value;
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a form of insertion sort. Your inner loop swaps the array values at index `j` and `j+1`, which is similar to [Wikipedia's pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm) for the algorithm, for instance, which also does a swap in the inner loop:

```
while i < length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    end while
    i ← i + 1
end while
```

Whether the inner loop does one or two array assignments is an implementation detail. It's more efficient to do just one assignment in the inner loop, of course, but for the purpose of introducing the algorithm to students, it may be easier to explain using "swaps".

Answer (score -1):

Yes, no matter how you slice it, you move around values inside the array and work in O(N^2) complexity - that is Insertion / Bubble sort.

Merge Sort will be more efficient, or in case your integers are bound in a narrow range - Bucket Sorting will be even quicker.

Comment: *"You move around values inside the array and work in O(n^2) complexity"* is not a sufficient condition for an algorithm to be insertion sort; and insertion sort is *not* the same as bubble sort. There are many other in-place O(n^2) sorting algorithms such as selection sort, shell sort, cocktail shaker sort, comb sort, etc. These are not insertion sort either.